# My tap event, mouse click event isn't recognizing the correct game object

Tags: unity-game-engine

My mouse click, tap event isn't recognizing the correct game object. I really can't figure out why

My code is just what I have seen in many Google searches.

I have `debug.logged` several variations just trying to get the game object I tap on:

```
// take_merchandise
// params: none
// functions : temporarily will rely on a click event and grab the merchandise from a cart
// returns: none
private void take_merchandise()
{


    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        Ray tap = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);

        RaycastHit hit;


        if (Physics.Raycast(tap, out hit))
        {
            Debug.Log(hit.transform.name);
        }

    }
}
```

I am getting the wrong game object.

Comment: Do you have multiple cameras on your scene? And what object it is currently hitting;

Comment: i do have multiple cameras and i havent figured it out what elements it hits.... it seems like it hits whatever it wants

Comment: Then you might want to specify which camera to raycast from; Instead of using `Camera.main`, use another camera instead.

Comment: Are you calling it inside Update method?

Answer (score 1):

Camera.main looks for the first camera in your hierarchy that has the tag "MainCamera".

If you use many cameras - this becomes a problem. The solution would be to either use other cameras in your script or tag all desired cameras as "MainCamera" and only keep 1 camera active at a time - that way the script will find it and use it (for example if you switch to Camera2, make sure to disable Camera1 so that Unity can get the correct camera from the hierarchy).

Comment: That is what I actually ended up doing anyways what is ridiculous is that when I wrote the code I saw Camera.main and knew exactly what I needed to do which is remember I’m using that specific camera. But then going through all the tutorials I kept seeing camera.main and I forgot what I was even doing so I appreciate your recommendation because I totally remembered I’m an idiot